# Plot chart like heat map with values from one column and color from another column

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have the following dataset with many rows, multiple samples and 3 columns. I need to plot a graph which looks like a heatmap but it should fill the color not just for the position but also till previous position.

```
Name    position    category
Sample1 15500   1
Sample1 15800   2
Sample1 16200   2
Sample1 17200   3
Sample1 17400   3
Sample1 17700   3
Sample1 18300   2
Sample1 20010   2
Sample1 22120   1
Sample1 30000   3
Sample2 15880   1
Sample2 16200   1
Sample2 16900   3
Sample2 18200   3
Sample2 18500   2
Sample2 20400   1
Sample2 21300   2
Sample2 24800   3
Sample2 26000   1
Sample2 30000   3
```

I first converted this to a pivot table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
sample_pivot=sample.pivot_table(columns="position" , index= "Name", values="category")
```

Then i used plotly to chart this

```
fig = px.imshow(sample_pivot)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[1, 35000])
fig.show()
```

I got the following chart

[image]

I need to modify above chart to fill the color in between the positions like below where the color filling will trace back to previous position and show up on the chart

```
Sample 1 : 
1-15500 --> Dark blue
15501-16200 --> orange red
16201-17700 --> yellow
17701-20010 --> orange red
20011-22120 --> Dark blue
22121-30000 --> yellow
```

Comment: You could normalize the value you want to classify and create a color scale with any color set for that normalized value. See the reference [here](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#custom-discretized-heatmap-color-scale-with-graph-objects) for more information.

Comment: what can i normalize here? i only have 3 values as categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following :

- In order to fill the region from 1 to the next known position, insert the corresponding column

  ```py
  sample_pivot.insert(0, 1, np.nan)
  ```
- Fill missing/NaN values using [`pandas.DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)

  ```py
  sample_pivot.bfill(axis=1, inplace=True)
  ```

[image: screenshot]

Note also that since the underlying trace used in this case is a `plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap`, you could use the parameter [`connectgaps`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-connectgaps), although it won't do exactly what you want, it might be interesting for you to see what it does.

Comment: Thank you ! This does exactly what i need. I tested on my dataset and it worked well. But, i didnt understand how 'z' data is used here as a concept. Can you point me to any documentation or how can i view the dataset after adding this parameter?

Comment: `z` refers to the image data, which in this case is a single channel (not rgb) 2D array built from your pivot table (the df contains one row per sample, so z is an array of [sample] array of positions). When using plotly express (ie. `px.imshow(data)`), for multichannel data plotly creates an image trace with `go.Image()`, whereas for single channel data it creates a heatmap trace with `go.Heatmap()`. In both situations, the image data goes in `z`, and in your case, it's a [heatmap](https://plotly.com/python/reference/heatmap/).

Comment: Actually, I could (or even should) have applied the backfill to the dataframe directly.. I think the way I did it in the first place is what confused you (?).. I just edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

One way i was thinking to generate what i wanted to get above is to have numbers in increments of 100 like 100,200,300,400 ... till 30,000 and fill blanks with Nan, perform outer join so that i have all positions including the incremented positions and use .bfill() method to fill and create above graph. Any suggestions on this or any better approach ?

Comment: Something like that ;) see my answer above.